# how to send an email on a condition when executing a job?

Tags: database, sql-server-2005

I'm running sql server 2005.  I want to create a step in a job which executes a stored procedure, gets a result from it, and after performing a check on it, send an email.  I've set up Database Mail under Management and tested it and it works fine.  I just don't know what the command is to send an email.  Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks

Riz

Answer (score 0):

You need [`EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx)